# JTable convert all values (ints, longs etc) to String

Tags: java, string, swing, jtable

I have a function that makes a TableModel and I'm working on something to copy the selected cell to the clipboard but the problem is let's say a table has a structure like this:

id|name

---

1 |shiv

I can copy the shiv correctly because it is a string but I can't copy the ID  because it isn't a string.

The function to make the TableModel is as follows:

```
public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs)
            throws SQLException {

        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
            columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
        }

        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
            for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
                vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
            }
            data.add(vector);
        }


        return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

    }
```

What should I change in it so that it works with all fields?

Comment: Have you tried `JTable#getValueAt(int, int)` which returns an `Object`, then using the instance of the `Object` and calling it's `toString` method?

Comment: confusion? is your table populated correctly? or error while getting value back?

Comment: @MadProgrammer has suggested what can be done. Rather unrelated question - why are you using `Vector`?

Comment: @ringbearer, the DefaultTableModel uses Vectors. The default models in Swing have not been updated to use the new List objects.

Comment: OK, for real applications, you might need to create your own table model and when you do that try using a List or an Array - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Answer (score 0):

```
table.getModel().getValueAt(row_index, col_index);
```

This will return selected element as object. If you want to convert it to int you need to parse.

```
int i = (Integer) object;
```

If it is long value

```
 Long a = (Long)object;
```